# LoadApplication(new App()) fails TypeLoadException in Xamarin Forms Acr.UserDialog

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I migrated my **Xamarin.Forms** app from Portable to **.NET Standard** because I need to add a function that requires the upgrade. I [finally] got everything to build, now when I start up either the Droid or iOS project, my app throws a

> TypeLoadException

[image: See screenshot]

I was under the impression this worked a lot smoother than it actually does. I need to get back to my original task which was adding the new functionality but I have to get the thing running first. I could really use, and appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: According to the plugin which the error is referring to (ACR User Dialogs) you need to set up it before using it. Did you put something like UserDialogs.Init(this); in your Android's MainActivity?

Comment: It's better you put the error message text here rather than a screenshot.